# Variable access - MySQL via PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I'm trying to add variables into MySQL. The Column Slot is of type INT and B1 -> B12 is of type VARCHAR(20).

$slot1 to $slot4 is a string.(Ex: 4PMTo6PM).The database connects and everything works well when I add hard coded data into the query. However

However when I pass it over using an NSURL, I dont seem to insert the data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   <?php
    $DB_hostname = "localhost";
    $DB_Name = "root";
    $DB_pass = "pwd";

    if(isset($_GET["tabName"])){
      $tableName = $_GET["tabName"];
      $slot1 = $_GET["slot1Timing"];
      $slot2 = $_GET["slot2Timing"];
      $slot3 = $_GET["slot3Timing"];
      $slot4 = $_GET["slot4Timing"]; 
     }

     $con = mysql_connect($DB_Hostname,$DB_Name,$DB_pass) or die(mysql_error());


     mysql_select_db("booking", $con);




      mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (Slot,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12)VALUES   
             ('1',$slot1,$slot1,$slot1,$slot1,$slot1,$slot1,$slot1,$slot1,$slot1,$slot1,$slot1,$slot1)");

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (Slot,B1, B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12)
             VALUES ('2',$slot2,$slot2,$slot2,$slot2,$slot2,$slot2,$slot2,$slot2,$slot2,$slot2,$slot2,$slot2)");

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (Slot,B1, B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12)
      VALUES ('3',$slot3,$slot3,$slot3,$slot3,$slot3,$slot3,$slot3,$slot3,$slot3,$slot3,$slot3,$slot3)");

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (Slot,B1, B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12)
       VALUES ('4',$slot4,$slot4,$slot4,$slot4,$slot4,$slot4,$slot4,$slot4,$slot4,$slot4,$slot4,$slot4)");


   mysql_close($con);
   ?>
```

***sample data*** (Working)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (Slot,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12)VALUES   
('1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',)");
```

**NSURL Connection**

```
   @"http://ip/booking/insertSlotsTable.php?tabName=%@&slot1Timing=%@&slot2Timing=%@&slot3Timing=%@&slot4Timing=%@",slotTableName,@"10AMTo12PM",@"12PMTo2PM",@"2PMTo4PM",@"4PMTo6PM"
```

Any one know what went wrong on the query variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `'` for string data to insert in query, same goes for all other queries.

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (Slot,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12)VALUES   
         ('1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1','$slot1')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of `$slot1` if it is empty it will not insert it will show error.

Better put `'$slot1'`, single quotes and try

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (Slot,B1, B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12)
             VALUES ('2','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."','".$slot2."')");
```

Comment: Its not empty. I Did echo the values.

Comment: Then put single quotes and try

Comment: If it is a string you need to put a single quote.